# what does this code snippet do (ternary operator)?

Tags: java, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

What does this code snippet do?

`((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "")`

Comment: Yes of cource because in both cases u had supplied blank space either n modulo 10 returns o or not.However the difference is "  " and "" both are blank but different in terms of whitespaces

Comment: There is a difference between " " and "". Please get your basics right.

Answer (score 0):

If the remainder of your number divided by ten isn't zero;

Then, **" "** (space)

Else, "" (empty string)

I'm sure something's missing.

Comment: I would've made that a comment but I can't comment on other ppl's stuff
What I don't know - and didn't answer - is what about it. in other words, what is done with the space or the empty string

Answer (score 0):

It returns a space if n is a not a common denominator of 10.

```
int n = 21;
String result = ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "");
System.out.println("---" + result + "---");
```

prints :

```
--- ---
```

Answer (score 0):

***ternaryCheck.java***

```
public class ternaryCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a;
        int n = 10; //if n = 10 Outputs My nameis ---- (With no space)
        //int n = 11; //if n = 11 Outputs My name is ---- (See the difference because there is a space in the middle)
        a = ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : ""); //" " --> means a space & "" --> means no space 
        System.out.println("My name"+a+"is --");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "")
```

is just

```
if (n % 10 != 0) {
    answer = " ";
} else {
    answer = "";
}
```

The one with space `" "` executes if the condition is true. otherwise `""` is executed;

Answer (score 0):

This is called the *ternary operator*!

Why is it called "ternary"? As you may know, a binary operator is one that operates on two operands. So a ternary operator operates on 3 operands.

What does it do? The ternary operator is just a fancy way to write an if statement. For instance, you have this piece of code

```
String myString = ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "");
```

This is the same as writing

```
String myString;
if (n % 10 != 0) {
    myString = " ";
} else {
    myString = "";
}
```

So if you translate the code into English,

> If n is not divisible by 10, set the value of myString to a space character. If n is divisible by 10, set the value of myString to an empty string.

Benefits:

- simplifies code
- more elegant
- concise

Disadvantages:

- hard to understand sometimes
- hard to maintain if you nest them